# how to create range date in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-8

i create script to compute range date in odoo. and my code look to long, and this my code :

def dateinformation(self):

```
     fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
     fmt1 = '%d'
     if self.selection_date:
         fromdt = self.selection_date
         plan = self.nursery_plandate
         conv_fromdt = datetime.strptime(str(fromdt),fmt)
         conv_plan = datetime.strptime(str(plan),fmt)
         d3 = conv_fromdt.month
         d4 = conv_plan.month
         d5 = conv_fromdt.day
         d6 = conv_fromdt.day
```

and this script to create range :

```
 if conv_fromdt and d4 :
             if d3 == d4:
                 if d5 == d6 :
                    self.nursery_information = '2'#pass
                 if d5 > d6 +  1:
                     self.nursery_information='2'
                 elif d5 > d6 + 2:
                     self.nursery_information='2'
                 elif d5 > d6 + 3:
                     self.nursery_information='2'
                 elif d5 > d6 + 4:
                     self.nursery_information='2'
                 elif d5 > d6 + 5:
                     self.nursery_information='2'
                 elif d5 > d6 + 6:
                     self.nursery_information='2'
                 elif d5 > d6 + 7:
                     self.nursery_information='2'
                 else :
                     self.nursery_information='1'#late
                 if d5 > d6 - 1:
                     self.nursery_information='2'
                 elif d5 > d6 - 2:
                     self.nursery_information='2'
                 elif d5 > d6 - 3:
                     self.nursery_information='2'
                 elif d5 > d6 - 4:
                     self.nursery_information='2'
                 elif d5 > d6 - 5:
                     self.nursery_information='2'
                 elif d5 > d6 - 6:
                     self.nursery_information='2'
                 elif d5 > d6 - 7:
                     self.nursery_information='2'
                 else  :
                     self.nursery_information='0'#untimely
```

and i want cut the script for simple script . anyone have idea?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to have the right type of fields.

If these field only contain a given date (but not hour/seconds), you can use the [`fields.Date`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.fields.Date) type of field.

If for another feature you need the time in this field, the following of this post will also work with the [`fields.Datetime`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.fields.Datetime) type, so you can also use it.

Once you use one of those two types for the fields, it is really easy to compute a day difference, you need (unless already done) to import the [fields file](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/fields.py) in the top of the file:

```
from openerp import fields
```

then in your method, you can simply use the `from_string` method from the `fields.Date`, which is explained in the [Odoo documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.fields.Date.from_string):

> #### `static from_string(value)`
>
> Convert an ORM `value` into a `date` value.

So only with a code like this, we have our day difference between two dates:

```
time_delta = fields.Date.from_string(self.selection_date) - fields.Date.from_string(self.nursery_plandate)
day_difference = time_delta.days
```

And all that is left is using basic python [comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) and [`if`/`elif`/`else` statments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements).

For example :

```
if 0 <= day_difference < 70:
    print "pass here when the day difference is between 0 and 69 (included)"
elif day_difference > -20:
    print "or pass here when the day difference is between -19 and -1 (included)"
else:
    print "otherwise (so less than -19 or more than 69)  pass here"
```